# Translate OData query to DataContract model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have an n-tier application. I have decoupled models between my internal types in backend and the ones that I'm exposing in my webApi publicly for the frontend.

I'm trying to use queries in Frontend using ODataQueryOptions, the problem that I'm facing is that frontend does not know the properties of my model. Is there a generic way to translate my frontend names exposed in webApi to internal properties names that ODataQueryOptions needs?

i.e. I can get property name from the query with this code.

```
 ODataQueryOptions<MyModel> queryString;
 if (queryString.OrderBy != null && queryString.OrderBy.OrderByClause != null)
 {
     foreach (OrderByNode node in queryString.OrderBy.OrderByNodes)
     {
         OrderByPropertyNode typedNode = node as OrderByPropertyNode;
     }
 }
```

I'm exposing my models doing the following.

```
public class MyModel
{        
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Name
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "name", EmitDefaultValue = false)]

    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

When I'm querying from the frontend I want to do it the following way because is what my webApi returns.

```
 http://localhost:8888/myModel?$orderby=name desc
```

But now I must do it with uppercase because is coupled to the backend

```
http://localhost:8888/jobs?$orderby=Name desc
```

Must I write manually the translation between properties? Or there are a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the System.Web.Http.OData or System.Web.OData?
If you use System.Web.OData you have name aliasing already implemented, and you can do what you want with no effort.